# Como obter uma string com o nome da janela que está com foco em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Há algum tempo comecei a usar o pyHook para manipular eventos. Entretanto, a versão original possui erros, portanto troquei-a por uma versão alternativa que corrigia os erros da versão original. Entretanto, descobri que essa versão alternativa mostra sempre uma string vazia para o método que retorna o nome da janela que está com foco.

```
from pyHook import HookManager
from python import PumpMessages

def evento_teclado(event):
    print(event.WindowName())
    return True

hm=HookManager()
hm.KeyDown=evento_teclado
hm.HookKeyboard()
PumpMessages()
```

Esse script sempre mostra uma string vazia. Existe algum outro jeito de obter o nome da janela?

Comment: Qual OS? Se for Windows, já tentou? `import win32gui
  win32gui.GetWindowText (w.GetForegroundWindow())`?

Comment: É Windows. E funcionou. Bota a resposta que aceito. @leonardopessoa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente utilizar o módulo `win32gui`:

`import win32gui 
window = win32gui.GetWindowText(w.GetForegroundWindow())`